# OpenGL: Wrong projection for rotating cube

Tags: c++, opengl, orthographic

I have the following blocks of code.

**OpenGL initialization:**

```
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    glOrtho(-WIDTH / (float) HEIGHT, WIDTH / HEIGHT, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

**OpenGL loop:**

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
    glRotatef(xrot,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);     
    glRotatef(yrot,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);     
    glRotatef(zrot,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);     
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {

        // The first of six sides
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-0.75f, -0.75f, 0.75f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.75f, -0.75f, 0.75f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.75f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.75f); 
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.75f);
        glVertex3f(-0.75f, 0.75f, 0.75f);   
       ....
```

Width = 800, heigh = 600. I expect to have a perfectly rotating cube; however, at some angles it does not look correct.

[image: Rotating cube]
I think that I have an issue in glOrtho as I don't know how to create the correct expression.

Comment: check glortho parameters from [this document](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) .You need to increase your far value (last parameter).

Comment: @CagkanToptas It didn't helped. I got the bigger cube, but I still see  clipped sides. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glPerspective() is better approach for 3D rendering instead of glOrtho(). Use glPerspective() to create the viewing volume.
When I replaced glOrtho() expression by 
`gluPerspective(45f, (float) WIDTH / (float) HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100f);`

I got the perfect cube.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

Your cube is clipped by the front and near planes. Your cube has an extent of of 1.5, and its center is 1 units away from your "camera", but your clipping range is just [-1,1] (relative to the camera), so that the farther edges will be out of the viewing frustum.

Comment: I tried to play with cube size, decreased it to 0.5 and even less, but unsuccessfully. It still clipped. Please check my answer. I found the solution.

Comment: Well 1+0.5 is still > 1, so what do you expect? Your perspective call uses a totally different clipping range of [0.1,100] - which you could use identically for the ortho call.

Comment: Oh, now I understood. I need refer to the documentation and get acquainted with the subject in greater detail. Thank you very much.